# Firebase Cloud Messaging Is Not Sending Notification On Device Using Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send the push notification on the device of the particular user, So I made the cloud function for that and you can see the cloud function code below section. The cloud function runs successfully without any error but the notification does not popUp in user's device. Here I add the cloud function code as well as the log attachment.

I am also tried the different solutions like by hitting the API and send the notification by also not getting success. So Coders Help Me To Jump Out Of This Issue.

**index.js**

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');
let admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/projects/{projectId}').onWrite(event => {
    var registrationToken = 'YOUR_Registration_Token';
    var message = {
      notification : {
            body : 'This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!',
            title : 'FCM Message'
      },
        data: {
            score: '850',
            time: '2:45'
        },
        token: registrationToken
    };

    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    admin.messaging().send(message)
    .then((response) => {
        // Response is a message ID string.
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
      return null;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    });
  console.log('hello');
});
```

[Here Are The Logs After Hitting Cloud Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPAmJ.png)

Comment: Looks like your missing some variables in ur payload. add `Content-available` to your payload and try again

Comment: Already Done But Then Also Not Getting Notification :(

Comment: Showing Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "content-available" at 'message': Cannot find a field.

Comment: You can also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message And I Also Get Same Response But Not Receiving The Notification.